# How to group tableview cells based on field in JSON array

Tags: ios, json, swift, tableview

Essentially I have am using JSON data to create an array and form a tableview.

I would like the table cells to be grouped by one of the fields from the JSON array.

This is what the JSON data looks like:

```
[{"customer":"Customer1","number":"122039120},{"customer":"Customer2","number":"213121423"}]
```

Each `number` needs to be grouped by each `customer`.

How can this be done?

This is how I've implemented the JSON data using the table:

**CustomerViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class CustomerViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, FeedCustomerProtocol {

    var feedItems: NSArray = NSArray()
    var selectedStock : StockCustomer = StockCustomer()
    let tableView = UITableView()
    @IBOutlet weak var customerItemsTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()



        //set delegates and initialize FeedModel
        self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
        self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true

        self.customerItemsTableView.delegate = self
        self.customerItemsTableView.dataSource = self

        let feedCustomer = FeedCustomer()

        feedCustomer.delegate = self
        feedCustomer.downloadItems()

            }


    }


    func itemsDownloaded(items: NSArray) {

        feedItems = items
        self.customerItemsTableView.reloadData()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // Return the number of feed items

        print("item feed loaded")
        return feedItems.count

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        // Retrieve cell

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customerGoods", for: indexPath) as? CheckableTableViewCell

        let cellIdentifier: String = "customerGoods"
        let myCell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier)!

        // Get the stock to be shown
        let item: StockCustomer = feedItems[indexPath.row] as! StockCustomer
        // Configure our cell title made up of name and price


        let titleStr = [item.number].compactMap { $0 }.joined(separator: " - ")


        return myCell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .none
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark

        let cellIdentifier: String = "customerGoods"
        let myCell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier)!
        myCell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .left


    }

}
```

**FeedCustomer.swift:**

```
import Foundation

protocol FeedCustomerProtocol: class {
    func itemsDownloaded(items: NSArray)
}


class FeedCustomer: NSObject, URLSessionDataDelegate {



    weak var delegate: FeedCustomerProtocol!

    let urlPath = "https://www.example.com/example/test.php"

    func downloadItems() {

        let url: URL = URL(string: urlPath)!
        let defaultSession = Foundation.URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)

        let task = defaultSession.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print("Error")
            }else {
                print("stocks downloaded")
                self.parseJSON(data!)
            }

        }

        task.resume()
    }

    func parseJSON(_ data:Data) {

        var jsonResult = NSArray()

        do{
            jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options:JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! NSArray

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)

        }

        var jsonElement = NSDictionary()
        let stocks = NSMutableArray()

        for i in 0 ..< jsonResult.count
        {

            jsonElement = jsonResult[i] as! NSDictionary

            let stock = StockCustomer()

            //the following insures none of the JsonElement values are nil through optional binding
            if let number = jsonElement[“number”] as? String,
                let customer = jsonElement["customer"] as? String,

            {

                stock.customer = customer
                stock.number = number
            }

            stocks.add(stock)

        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in

            self.delegate.itemsDownloaded(items: stocks)

        })
    }
}
```

**StockCustomer.swift:**

```
import UIKit

class StockCustomer: NSObject {

    //properties of a stock

    var customer: String?
    var number: String?


    //empty constructor

    override init()
    {

    }

    //construct with @name and @price parameters

    init(customer: String) {

        self.customer = customer



    }



    override var description: String {
        return "Number: \(String(describing: number)), customer: \(String(describing: customer))"

    }

}
```

Comment: Do you want to create sections for each customer?

Comment: You must close the questions once it is satisfactorily answered by accepting the answer. This will let others know and people will focus on other unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by making an array of array. So something like this

`[[{"customer": "customer1", "number": "123"}, {"customer": "customer1", "number": "456"}], [{"customer": "customer2", "number": "678"}, {"customer": "customer2", "number": "890"}]]`

This is not the only data structure you can use to group. Another possibility is:

`{"customer1": [{"customer": "customer1", "number": "123"}, {"customer": "customer1", "number": "456"}], "customer2": [{"customer": "customer2", "number": "678"}, {"customer": "customer2", "number": "890"}]}`

Then you can use UITableView `sections` to group by customers. Section count would be the number of inside arrays and each section would contain as many rows as there are numbers in that inside array.

Comment: There is nothing I could add to the code I currently have?

Comment: You definitely have to make that data structure and then use https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614924-numberofsections

Answer (score 0):

You can group a `sequence` based on a particular key using one of the `Dictionary` `initializer`,

```
init(grouping:by:)
```

The above method `init` will group the given `sequence` based on the key you'll provide in its `closure`.

Also, for parsing such kind of `JSON`, you can easily use `Codable` instead of manually doing all the work.

So, for that first make `StockCustomer` conform to `Codable` protocol.

```
class StockCustomer: Codable {
    var customer: String?
    var number: String?
}
```

Next you can parse the array like:

```
func parseJSON(data: Data) {
    do {
        let items = try JSONDecoder().decode([StockCustomer].self, from: data)
        //Grouping the data based on customer
        let groupedDict = Dictionary(grouping: items) { $0.customer } //groupedDict is of type - [String? : [StockCustomer]]
        self.feedItems = Array(groupedDict.values)
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Read about `init(grouping:by:)` in detail here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/3127163-init

Make the `feedItems` object in `CustomerViewController` of type `[[StockCustomer]]`

Now, you can implement UITableViewDataSource methods as:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.feedItems.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customerGoods", for: indexPath) as! CheckableTableViewCell
    let items = self.feedItems[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = items.compactMap({$0.number}).joined(separator: " - ")
    //Configure the cell as per your requirement
    return cell
}
```

Try implementing the approach with all the bits and pieces and let me know in case you face any issues.

Comment: Didn't get you. What address?

Comment: I am having some trouble implementing your method into my code, I haven't worked JSON serialization very much. When I add your code to my code it causes alot of different errors to appear. Can you please try posting your code integrated into mine?

Comment: I really appreciate it